# Save Form to Database and Sent to a php file

Tags: php, database, forms, payment-gateway, payment

I have a form that get some info such as firstname, lastname, email, address, zipcode, etc. .
I wanna users fill this fields and pay money with a gatway(Payline).

My problem : 
When users pay money, field will be sent to payline gateway, but I need store fields data on a database, too.

what I have to do?

Comment: Can you show us some code? It's all on how they set up the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will fulfill you need

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function{
   $('input[type="submit"].click(function(){

  var alldata= $('#form_id").serializeArray();

  $.ajax({
         type:"post",
        url: "any.php",/* create php page, store all serialize data in variable using $_POST['your field'] and perform sql query to save it on mysql */
        data: myData,
        dataType:"html".
        success:function(){
         alert("your all form data has been saved in mysql table");

              }

       });
       });
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a project in which i stored data in a temp table first then redirected user to gatewat (Paypal) for payment. After successful payment they are redirected back to my success page and then i transfer the data from temp table to my main table on page load.
I created this in asp.net so can't help u much in php but u can implement this logic.

Comment: Would You Please give the project ?